# Is it safe to reuse the array passed to .apply()?

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing

I need to create wrapper functions around other functions. It is well known that arguments object is quite cranky and can't be passed to any function verbatim. Array creation in V8 is not cheap either. So the fastest code I could come up with is this:

```js
function wrap (fun) {      
  // reuse the same array object for each call
  var args = [];
  var prevLen = 0;
  
  return function () {
    
    // do some wrappy things here
    
    // only set args.length if it changed (unlikely)
    var l = arguments.length;
    if (l != prevLen) {
      prevLen = args.length = l;
    }
    
    // copy the args and run the functon
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    fun.apply(this, args);
    
  };
  
}

var test = wrap(function (rec) {
  document.write(arguments[1] + '<br />');
  if (rec) test(false, 'something else');
  document.write(arguments[1] + '<br />');
});
test(true, 'something');
```

This way I avoid creating or changing length of the array object unless really needed. The performance gain is quite serious.

The problem: I use the same array all over the place and it could change before the function call is finished (see example)

**The question:** is the array passed to .apply() copied to somewhere else in *all* JavaScript implementations? Is it guaranteed by the current EcmaScript spec that the fourth line of output will never ever be `something else`?

It works fine in all the browsers I checked, but I want to be future-proof here.

Comment: Depends a lot on what these `// do some wrappy things here` are. Can you show us what you are doing there?

Comment: Why are you using an array at all instead of `fun.apply(this, arguments)`?

Comment: @Bergi 1) I don't do anything related to the arguments, but that shouldn't matter here I think 2) because passing "arguments" as an argument to any function (even .apply()) disables optimization in V8 (and I think everywhere else too)

Comment: This IEFE is totally unnecessary btw, you've already got a function scope.

Comment: 1) well, if it does call some user-supplied function, *that* could create some hazards with your static-`args` approach. 2) No, passing `arguments` to `apply` is perfectly fine in V8

Comment: @Bergi sorry then, I'm pretty certain it wasn't at some point. In any case in the real world scenario I add 2 additional arguments so passing unmodified arguments is not an option.

Comment: @Bergi also you're right about the IIFE, I messed my scopes up. *blushes and edits that thing out*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the array passed to `.apply()` copied to somewhere else, and is it guaranteed by the current EcmaScript spec?

Yes. The [`apply` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply) does convert the array (or whatever you pass in) to a separate arguments list using [`CreateListFromArrayLike`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createlistfromarraylike), which is then passed around and from which the `arguments` object for the call is created as well as the parameters are set.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply) it is indeed supposed to be copied so the code seems to be safe.

> Let argList be CreateListFromArrayLike(argArray).
>
> Return Call(func, thisArg, argList).